# Keyboard gets dismissed immediately after deleting the last character in the textinput field - Formik - React Native

Tags: android, ios, formik, user-experience, react-native-textinput

As described in the title.

This happens in both: IOS and Android, iPad also.

note:
<TextInputs in other screens don't have this behaviour: not <TextInput nor <TextInput used inside Formik's form.

Formik's props that I am using:

- fields
- initialValues
- validationSchema
- onSubmit
- submitButtonText
- withoutScrollView
- buttonLoading
- allowSubmission

<TextInput props that I am using:

- type
- fieldKey
- placeholder
- props: {
  keyboardType: 'number-pad',
  inputPattern: appConstants.commonRegex.onlyInt,}

I've tried everything I could, so far:

- Cleaning and removing unnecessary lines that I don't need; like form reference.
- Modifying/commenting out each part separately of the two components (Formik & TextInput) like in their props; to debug this issue.

I am expecting a regular behavior: not dismissing the keyboard after deleting <TextInput's value or when making it blank.